Quantum chaos and tunnel effect
In quantum chaos, more concretely in quantum billiards, when an electron is moving within some certain chaotic-shaped domain, scars may appear if you introduce some losses on the boundaries where the propagating particle bounces. In this model, every time the particle bounces it flips its spin. Furthermore, for scars to appear, you have to suppose that a little part of the wave function of the propagating particle goes through the wall of the billiard. So is quantum scarring related to quantum tunneling or is it more related to the spin being flipped?

It might be a good idea to provide a reference to a paper about electrons about "some certain chaotic-shaped domain".

This one for instance https://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/97882/1/131202-lattice_scars-njp-sent.pdf

As far as I know you do not need dissipation for quantum scarring. Please verify the source that says that.

It has been told to me my two thesis directors. Thanks for your opinion. Maybe it's just that with dissipation they appear more easily

This is a quote from the paper you cited (I have put the relevant part in bold for emphasis):

Results of quantum chaos have been particularly remarkable in the study of billiards: domains wherein a particle moves ballistically except for elastic collisions with the boundary. One of the most surprising results in this field was the discovery by Heller [4] that the probability amplitude of certain wavefunctions—called “scarred wavefunctions” or, simply, “scars”—in a chaotic two-dimensional billiard is not uniform but concentrates along the trajectory of classical periodic orbits. This effect due to wave interference has now been observed in a number of systems, from microwaves in cavities [5, 6], to electrons in quantum dots [7, 8], to optical fibers [9].

Quantum scarring is a result of quantum interference.

But that is not to say much because all the structure formed is due to interference, whether they are scars or not. Maybe the next paper I'm going to publish make this point clear. Although I keep without knowing what's going on in the bounce
